# Implementing PDE as Loss Function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with SciANN (based on TensorFlow) and I have a specific requirement for my loss function. Here's the context:

- I have two variables `x` and `y`.
- I am dealing with a function `f`.
- I want to set up my loss function based on a specific form of PDE `f(x-1, y+3) - x*y = 0`.

My question is
How would I represent `f(x-1, y+3)` within TensorFlow? I am unsure how to correctly express this operation to include it as part of my loss function.

Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

### my try

SCIANN (based on tensorflow):

```
x = sn.Variable('x')
y = sn.Variable('y')
u = sn.Functional('u', [x, y], 5 * [40], 'tanh', res_net=True)

L = u.eval([x-1,y+3]) - x*y
```